# Is there a way to pause all threads from the main one in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep, pause, suspend

Basically is that. Lets say I have a program with 6 threads (including the main one). Is there a way to pause/sleep/suspend all the other 5 threads from the main one? lets say by getting their ID then used it to suspend all of them (or by any other method).

Comment: `Thread.suspend()` and some supporting methods have been deprecated and no longer work (check the Java doc).  I know of no other method other than some homegrown ones.  And even those might introduce the same deadlock problem caused by suspend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you all the threads of the application created so far

```
Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
```

To stop a thread you will have to write your own customized thread class like explained in this example which is using a flag to control the thread execution

https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-stop

While iterating over the set of the threads **threadSet** set the value of the flag to make it stop